# Formating figure and table to be side by side on beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, formatting, diagrams, powerpoint

I have this

[image]

I want them to be on one slide side by side. I tried using minipage to know success whatsoever. Here is my entire latex code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{multicol}
% %\usepackage[labelfont={color=bf}]{caption}
% % Changes the Font size on a particular slide
\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{8}{8.2}\selectfont}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.0cm,text margin right=1.0cm}
\title{XGBoost: Using a Tree Boosting Algorithm to Predict the Probability of Default  }
\author{Morgan Weiss}
\institute{Aspen Capital}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frame{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}



\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Objectives}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Objectives}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Short-term Objective: Create a more accurate model to predict the probability of default.
    \item Long-term Objective: To improve the accuracy of cash-flow projections.
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{1.png}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Methodologies}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Methodologies}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Model:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item XGBoost
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Additive tree model: add new trees that complement the already built ones.
            \item Reponse is the optimal linear combination of all decision trees.
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{2.png}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Data and Features Used}
\begin{frame}[shrink=11]
\frametitle{Data and Features Used}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Number of loans in data set: $13,216$ (includes both active and inactive).
    \item Features ($x$ variables):
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Demographic:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Age of borrower as of service transfer date.
            \item Fico score (current).
            \item Education (Melissa database).
            \item Marital status (Melissa database).
            \item Presence of children.
            \item Household size.
            \item Gender (Melissa database).
            \item Household income (Melissa database).
            \item Length of residence. 
        \end{itemize}
        \columnbreak
        \item Property specific:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item State.
            \item Distance to nearest metropolitan city.
            \item Year built.
            \item Square footage of property.
            \item Lotsize (in sqft).
        \end{itemize}
        \item Loan specific:
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Current UPB.
            \item Purchased UPB.
            \item Purchased value.
            \item Purchased LTV.
            \item Original interest rate.
            \item Bidding status.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{multicols}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Predictor: Default flag, how is it calculated?}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Default flag ($\hat{y}$)
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Calculated from
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Loan status.
            \item Days delinquent.
            \item Bidding status (old and new).
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}



\section{Section 2}

\subsection{Model Output}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Model Output}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \scalebox{0.6}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    & \textbf{Training Set} & \textbf{Testing Set} \\ \hline
    \textbf{Accuracy} & 0.780079 & 0.7545 \\ \hline
    \textbf{AUC Score} & 0.873782 & 0.822150 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.43\textwidth]{3.png}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Model Output (cont.)}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \scalebox{0.75}{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        & \textbf{Testing Set} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Error Rate} & 0.245461 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Sensitivity} & 0.695352 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Specificity} & 0.695352 \\ \hline
        \textbf{False Positive Rate} & 0.228793 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{4.png}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}



\section{Conclusion}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Summary}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Just to clarify I want the table and pictures to be on one slide side by side next to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `columns` for that. What I do not know is whether or not all these slides of section 1 and the summary are also to be changed. I also do not have your figures `1.png` and so on.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
%\usepackage{multicol}
% %\usepackage[labelfont={color=bf}]{caption}
% % Changes the Font size on a particular slide
\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{8}{8.2}\selectfont}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.0cm,text margin right=1.0cm}
\title{XGBoost: Using a Tree Boosting Algorithm to Predict the Probability of Default  }
\author{Morgan Weiss}
\institute{Aspen Capital}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
% \begin{frame}
% \titlepage
% \end{frame}
% 
% \begin{frame}
% \frame{Outline}
% \tableofcontents
% \end{frame}



% \section{Section 1}
% 
% \subsection{Objectives}
% \begin{frame}
% \frametitle{Objectives}
% \begin{itemize}
%     \item Short-term Objective: Create a more accurate model to predict the probability of default.
%     \item Long-term Objective: To improve the accuracy of cash-flow projections.
% \end{itemize}
% \begin{figure}
%     \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
% \end{figure}
% \end{frame}
% 
% \subsection{Methodologies}
% \begin{frame}
% \frametitle{Methodologies}
% \begin{itemize}
%     \item Model:
%     \begin{itemize}
%         \item XGBoost
%         \begin{enumerate}
%             \item Additive tree model: add new trees that complement the already built ones.
%             \item Reponse is the optimal linear combination of all decision trees.
%         \end{enumerate}
%     \end{itemize}
% \end{itemize}
% \begin{figure}
%     \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-b}
% \end{figure}
% \end{frame}
% 
% \subsection{Data and Features Used}
% \begin{frame}[shrink=11]
% \frametitle{Data and Features Used}
% \begin{itemize}
%     \item Number of loans in data set: $13,216$ (includes both active and inactive).
%     \item Features ($x$ variables):
%     \begin{multicols}{2}
%     \begin{itemize}
%         \item Demographic:
%         \begin{itemize}
%             \item Age of borrower as of service transfer date.
%             \item Fico score (current).
%             \item Education (Melissa database).
%             \item Marital status (Melissa database).
%             \item Presence of children.
%             \item Household size.
%             \item Gender (Melissa database).
%             \item Household income (Melissa database).
%             \item Length of residence. 
%         \end{itemize}
%         \columnbreak
%         \item Property specific:
%         \begin{itemize}
%             \item State.
%             \item Distance to nearest metropolitan city.
%             \item Year built.
%             \item Square footage of property.
%             \item Lotsize (in sqft).
%         \end{itemize}
%         \item Loan specific:
%         \begin{itemize}
%             \item Current UPB.
%             \item Purchased UPB.
%             \item Purchased value.
%             \item Purchased LTV.
%             \item Original interest rate.
%             \item Bidding status.
%         \end{itemize}
%     \end{itemize}
%     \end{multicols}
% \end{itemize}
% \end{frame}
% 
% \begin{frame}
% \frametitle{Predictor: Default flag, how is it calculated?}
% \begin{itemize}
%     \item Default flag ($\hat{y}$)
%     \begin{itemize}
%         \item Calculated from
%         \begin{itemize}
%             \item Loan status.
%             \item Days delinquent.
%             \item Bidding status (old and new).
%         \end{itemize}
%     \end{itemize}
% \end{itemize}
% \end{frame}
% 
% 
% 
\section{Section 2}

\subsection{Model Output}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Model Output}
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \scalebox{0.6}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    & \textbf{Training Set} & \textbf{Testing Set} \\ \hline
    \textbf{Accuracy} & 0.780079 & 0.7545 \\ \hline
    \textbf{AUC Score} & 0.873782 & 0.822150 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Model Output (cont.)}
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \scalebox{0.75}{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        & \textbf{Testing Set} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Error Rate} & 0.245461 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Sensitivity} & 0.695352 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Specificity} & 0.695352 \\ \hline
        \textbf{False Positive Rate} & 0.228793 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.85\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

% 
% 
% \section{Conclusion}
% \begin{frame}
% \frametitle{Summary}
% 
% \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

As for your comment, you may also use a simple tabular.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{8}{8.2}\selectfont}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1.0cm,text margin right=1.0cm}
\title{XGBoost: Using a Tree Boosting Algorithm to Predict the Probability of Default  }
\author{Morgan Weiss}
\institute{Aspen Capital}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\section{Section 2}

\subsection{Model Output}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Model Output}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \scalebox{0.6}{
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    & \textbf{Training Set} & \textbf{Testing Set} \\ \hline
    \textbf{Accuracy} & 0.780079 & 0.7545 \\ \hline
    \textbf{AUC Score} & 0.873782 & 0.822150 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
&     $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-c}}}$
\\[5em]
\pause
   \scalebox{0.75}{
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        & \textbf{Testing Set} \\ \hline
        \textbf{Error Rate} & 0.245461 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Sensitivity} & 0.695352 \\ \hline
        \textbf{Specificity} & 0.695352 \\ \hline
        \textbf{False Positive Rate} & 0.228793 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
&
$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-duck}}}$
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what I wanted was the pictures and tables to be on one slide meaning taking those two slides and putting them into one. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Wolfy I added something along those lines.